# What is the best way to use sessionStorage in angular 6

Tags: angular6, session-storage

Im trying to build web application spring boot as backend and angular as frontend, but im facing some issue regarding to session and getting data for all components.

Im using sessionStorage.setItem() when user login in 
But when I try to get user data in my home im using sessionStorage.getItem(). 
The issue that I  have to refresh the pages to fill the data.

Can you please help me with best practice to fill the data without refreshing all pages?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what are you pointing out by "fill the data without refreshing all pages" this.

But when you store the data in either sessionStorage or localStorage you can get the data whenever you navigate to your components through 'router-outlet'.

you can use ngOnInit() to get the data from sessionStorage, since it will be called whenever a component is initialized and whenever a particular page is refreshed.

You can get the data using following code, Assuming your key is 'data'.

```
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('data')) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'))); //converts to json object
    } else {
      console.log('key dose not exists');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest you to use localStorage its same as session storage but persists more than even the browser is closed and reopened.

```
// Set item:
let myObj = { name: 'Skip', breed: 'Labrador' };

localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

// Getitem:

```
let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
```